# How to close pop up after click on button?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 `Button` in my pop up, when I click on a button the new `Activity` opens, but when I go back on the first `Activity` the pop up stays open. How can I close this pop up when I click on button?

```
public void ShowPopUp(){
        popUpDialog.setContentView(R.layout.pop_up_dash);
        close = popUpDialog.findViewById(R.id.close_pop_up);
        btnMap = popUpDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_pop_map);
        btnList = popUpDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_pop_list);

        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popUpDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
      popUpDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
      popUpDialog.show();


}


btnSnack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ShowPopUp();
                btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String type = "snack";

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),                 
MapsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("location", type);
                        startActivity(intent);
   }
   });
```

Comment: You can dismiss the popup while navigating to a new Activity.

Answer (score 4):

Just invoke `popUpDialog.dismiss();` in `btnMap`'s `View.OnClickListener` right before starting a new `Activity`.